# Order of axis in set builder notation.

Tags: functions

Can I write the set builder notation of $\{x | x < 1\}$ in the form of  $\{x | 1 > x\}$? Most examples seem to put the axis first and I'm wondering if putting concrete number first is legal?

Comment: Sure, since the conditions $x < 1$ and $1 > x$ are equivalent, you can use either one (author's choice). Personally, I prefer $x < 1$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please edit and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format math expressions.

Comment: I have made an attempt at formatting the expressions; still reading through the guide question you linked to and will adjust as a learn more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x<1$ and $1>x$ are the same thing, so you can use them both. People prefer $x<1$, but this choice is guided by habit or personal taste.